# There are no available emulators-blocked: the user operation is waiting for background work to complete

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am very new to mobile application and Titanium Appcelerator; I downloaded the IDE and when I want to install Android SDK, Blackbery SDK or Tizen SDK in the IDE : it keeps saying : blocked: the user operation is waiting for background work to complete; even after 1 hour the same message! Why is that! I don't find any background work!

Also when I want to run my application, it only runs on browser not "Android Device" or "Android Emulator"; if I use "Android Device" or "Android Emulator" it gives me an error and says: "There are no available emulators" or "There are no Android devices connected"; although my Android phone is connected!

Could you please help me in this regard and if you need more clarification, please let me know

Your help is totally appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try out is to install Android SDK separately and give the path to the Android SDK inside the Titanium studio.